# Is there a more concise way to write css margin string in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

I wrote a function that takes in an object of css margin properties and outputs just the necessary values for css shorthand in an array. For example if the top is the same as the bottom and the right is the same as the left you only really need the two values.

```
const marginDedupe = ({ top = 0, left = 0, right = 0, bottom = 0 }) => {
  if (top === right && top === bottom && top === left) {
    return [top];
  } else if (top === bottom && right === left) {
    return [top, right];
  } else if (right === left) {
    return [top, right, bottom];
  } else {
    return [top, right, bottom, left];
  }
};
```

So for example:

```
marginDedupe(10,30,50,20); // [10,30,50,20]
marginDedupe(10,30,10,30); // [10,30]
marginDedupe(10,30,50,30); // [10,30,50]
marginDedupe(10,10,10,10); // [10]
```

What I've got now works but looks terrible. Is there a more concise way of writing this or is this just the way to do it?

Comment: this is more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ than SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method is more concise / [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)-er - it doesn't repeat condition tests - but I wouldn't say it's that much easier to read:

```
const marginDedupe = ({ top = 0, left = 0, right = 0, bottom = 0 }) => {
  if (right === left) {
    if (top === bot) {
      if (top === right) return [top];
      return [top, right];
    }
    return [top, right, bottom];
  }
  return [top, right, bottom, left];
};
```

Comment: Definitely looks cleaner, but yea to me its slightly less semantic / readable

Answer (score -1):

You an use Set to produce an array without duplicates ie.

`const set1 = new Set([10, 20, 30, 40]);
   console.log(set1); // Set(4){10, 20, 30, 40}`

`const set1 = new Set([10, 20, 10, 20]);
   console.log(set1); // Set(2){10, 20}`

Comment: Unfortunatly this won't quite work because a value is only removed if it's adjacent value is the same as itself. This just removes any pairings. For example: [10,10,10,20] has to be (in css) written out 10px 10px 10px 20px. Set will just return 10, 20, which will be interpreted as 10px 20px 10px 20px.

Comment: It may allow for a more simple if/else statement though.